# can't connect to web server remotely

Tags: iis-7

I have web site served via IIS 7. I can access it locally (on the network/LAN), but cannot access it from other computers on the Internet.

Could you please explain how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You will get a better answer if you provide us with your internal server LAN IP and your public internet IP and also a description of how your internal server is wired up to the Internet.

Comment: You're kidding right?  S/He doesn't need to supply actual IP addresses - just the topology and whether there are any firewalls in the way.

Answer (score 0):

This is better suited for serverfault, but you need to diagnose the problem using a bottom up approach.

first , go through this checklist.

1) is your physical cabling working

2) is your routing to the server working ?

3) are the ports to the webserver working ? Check any firewall running ?

4) is the web server instance configured properly to let you access remotely ?